# elasticsearch combining muti-word token to single token

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, elasticsearch-analyzers

Basically, Let's say I have a list phrases in vocabulary

```
- University of Texas Dallas
- University of Tokyo
- University of Toronto
```

Let's say I have 3 documents

```
- doc1: I study at University of Texas Dallas and its awsome 
- doc2: I study at University of Tokyo and its awsome            
- doc3: I study at University of Toronto and its awsome
```

By using a whitespace tokenizer the following tokens would be identified in the index

```
-doc1: ["i", "study", "in", "university", "of", "texas", "dallas", "and", "its", "awsome"]
-doc2: ["i", "study", "in", "university", "of", "tokyo", "and", "its", "awsome"]
-doc3: ["i", "study", "in", "university", "of", "toronto", "and", "its", "awsome"]
```

However, Since I have a known "vocabulary", I would like to phrase tokenize and achieve the following

```
-doc1: ["i", "study", "in", "university of texas dallas", "and", "its", "awsome"]
-doc2: ["i", "study", "in", "university of tokyo", "and", "its", "awsome"]
-doc3: ["i", "study", "in", "university of toronto", "and", "its", "awsome"]
```

How do I achieve phrase tokenization given I have a list of phrases in vocabulary?

Comment: Just curious, Why you need to index it as a single term? Phrase/Span queries should solve the querying problem.

Comment: if I do not index it as a single token...and...If I search for "Toronto" I get the result "university of Toronto", SImilarly If I search phrase "texas"...I get the result "university of texas Dallas" ......My application needs to avoid these results.
.................................................
PS: sorry for the poor example

Comment: @Nirmal Basically, I don't want to match a subset of words present in the vocabulary...It should match only for full phrase "University of Tokyo", not for "Tokyo"

Comment: I am not sure if there are built-in tokenizers to do it based on the dictionary. This may be a good reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html